# Angular 2x - Não realizar databinding para 2 objetos iguais

Tags: angular

No meu componente tenho 2 objetos que utilizam o mesmo modelo, como abaixo:

**Componente:**

```
produtos: Produto[] = [];
produtosOriginal: Produto[] = [];
```

Em determinado momento faço a cópia dos valores:

```
this.produtosOriginal = this.produtos;
```

No HTML, eu faço um for e vinculo o input a propriedade:

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let produto of produtos; let i = index;">
   ...

   <input class="form-control form-control-sm"
          type="number"
          min="1"
          step="1"
          (focusout)="validarItem(produto.id)" 
          (input)="validarItem(produto.id)"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': produto.erroQtde }" 
          [(ngModel)]="produto.qtde" />
</ng-container>
```

Quando realizo uma alteração no input **o valor é repassado para os 2 objetos**, já verifiquei se esse valor está sendo passado por outro fator, mais com certeza o problema está com o [(ngModel)]. Como consigo atualizar somente o objeto **produtos**.

Observação:

1. Estou utilizando Angular 8.
2. Já tentei utilizar [(ngModel)]="produtos[i].valor" mais sem resultado.

Comment: A lista `produtos` é uma cópia de `produtosOriginal`? se for você vai ter de copiar uma para outra usando spread (`...`). Ficaria assim a assimilação: `produtos = {...produtosOriginal};` assim a alteração em "produtos" não reflete em "produtosOriginal".

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem, pq tem 2 variáveis diferentes com o mesmo tipo de objeto no mesmo componente?

Comment: Se você estiver populando ```produtos``` através da ```produtosOriginal``` da seguinte forma: ```this.produtos = this.produtosOriginal;``` você não está passando os valores, está passando a referencia. Logo ```produtos``` aponta pra ```produtosOriginal```, e qualquer alteração em ```produtos``` irá alterar ```produtosOriginal```. Espero que de pra entender...

Comment: Leonardo Getulio, tentei fazer como você passou, só que para minha lógica seria o inverso: 
 this.produtosOriginal = { ... this.produtos }; só que não consigo mais acessar os métodos por ex: this.produtosOriginal.length

Comment: Lucas Ayrosa, qual seria então a maneira correta de popular uma cópia?

Comment: Da forma que o @LeonardoGetulio falou mesmo, só que acredito que o único equívoco foi as chaves... Seria: ```this.produtosOriginal = [...this.produtos];```. Teste e veja se irá resolver seu problema.

Comment: this.produtosOriginal = [...this.produtos] = continua refletindo / this.produtosOriginal = {...this.produtos} = perde-se os métodos de "produtosOriginal"

Comment: Método ou propriedade? Se for método é provável que vá perder mesmo. Se for propriedade/valor não deveria perder, esta função é nativa, entretanto pode varrer o array e dar .push() em cada objeto devendo antes assimilar em uma constante. Exemplo: `const copiaProduto = {...produtosOriginal[0]}; produtos.push(copiaProduto);`. Testa ai, qualquer coisa chama aqui.

Comment: Refletir você quer dizer que continua modificando os dois arrays? Porque não deveria acontecer isso. Você pode testar rapidamente no console do navegador criando um array de exemplo, copiando esse pra outro do jeito que estava fazendo ```a = b``` e criar um terceiro com ```c = [...a]```, modifica os valores de ```b``` e ```c``` e verá que apenas a alteração de ```b``` influencia em ```a```. De qualquer forma, tem outro jeito de copiar valores: ```this.produtosOriginal = this.produtos.slice();```. Pode testar, se quiser.

Comment: Se utilizo o this.produtosOriginal = { ...this.produtos } perco os métodos .find(), filter(), etc.. / Se utilizo this.produtosOriginal = [ ...this.produtos ] tudo que altero em produtos reflete em produtosOriginal. Sobre estar funcionando no console realmente funciona, talvez seja algo com o ngModel, sinceramente não sei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve clonar o objeto para que isso não ocorra, segue os exemplos de como você pode estar fazendo isso.

> Método 01

```
this.produtosOriginal = [ ... this.produtos ];
```

> Método 02

```
this.produtosOriginal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.produtos));
```

Comment: pra copiar arrays tem que ser com colchetes

Comment: @EduardoVargas corrigido, não me atentei que era vetor.

Comment: O método 02 funcionou, no entanto, o método 1 que parece mais 'limpo' continua refletindo as alterações efetuadas em this.produtos.

Comment: @Alessandro eu atualizei a resposta, tente com a nova resposta.

Comment: @HiagoSouza, já tinha tentando após sua alteração, mais ainda persistia em refletir, pelo que percebi ele cria uma cópia superficial, optei por utilizar uma abordagem diferente que também funcionou: this.produtosOriginal = this.produtos.map(objeto => ({...objeto})); Sugiro que inclua na sua resposta. Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira rapida de clonar uma matriz..

```
clone(fn) {
    const arr = [...Array(1000000)];
    console.time('timer');
    fn(arr);
    console.timeEnd('timer');
}
```

Nota: dentre todas as maneiras, a única maneira de clonar profundamente uma matriz é usando

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)).
```